# Outlook 2013 (exchange online) sub folders move themselves up and down

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm facing a problem in our company which I've never seen before and which is really strange in my opinion. In our company we have about 30-40 client computer with MS Outlook 2013 installed. On some clients the sub folders of a mailbox are jumping up and down for themselves. It's not on every computer and there is no regularity, but it's always the same mailbox and always the same three folders (inbox, sent items and deleted items).

Well my google researches suggested some hints, but unfortunately no solution for this problem. The suggestions I tried were:

- Manually move the inbox back to top (this was a suggestion which helped some users to get rid of the problem, but not in my case)
- Right Click on root node > `Sort Subfolders A to Z`
- File > Options > Advanced > Display > Check checkbox `Disable hardware graphics acceleration`

Some users could solve their problems trying those suggestions, unfortunately not me. What I also thought could help is to fix the sort order of the subfolders, so it cannot be changed manually, but I couldn't find an option for this and I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Is this a known bug and is there a fix for it?

**EDIT:**

The mailbox in which this problem is happening is a shared mailbox in MS exchange online.

**Update:**

Okay I tried the following without success:

- Run Outlook using the following parameter: `/resetnavpane`, `/cleanviews`, `cleanrules` (be aware: cleanrules will delete all the rules in all mailboxes which the users is connected with)
- Open Outlook in safe mode
- Uninstalled the latest Windows Updates (January 14th 2016 - later versions are from December 2015 where the problem has not existed yet).

As I mentioned above, without any success. The folders still do what they want. Further suggestions appreciated.

**Update:**

Disable the check box for cached mode (`File > Account Settings > Change > Use Cached Exchange Mode`) solved the problem (see also SimonS suggestions in the answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running outlook with one of the following commands

```
/resetnavpane
/cleanviews
/cleanrules (this will delete all rules of all mailboxes - attention!)
```

if that doesn't help

- try opening Outlook in safe mode to disable 3rd party add-ins
- Turning cached mode on/off
- create a new profile

The new profile will set outlook back to default settings.

if that doesn't help, deinstall the latest windows updates.

cheers!

Comment: Please notice my update.

Comment: Disable the check box for cached mode solved the problem. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Found that if one person moves a sub-folder in a shared mailbox it will moved for the other people sharing that mailbox.  Tested it with a colleague the result was almost immediate.

Comment: Are you proposing one of the users of the mailbox is moving the Inbox, Sent Items, and/or Deleted Items folder into a subfolder? Because that's impossible to do.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Your post is addressing a really old question and doesn't appear to add additional info to help.  You will find that you will have a better experience if you take moment to take the Stack Overflow [tour].  If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.